# WebDriver save problems in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I'm using Java+ChromeDriver on Mac for my project.
Here is some code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", TestConfig.driverURL());
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless").addArguments("window-size=2560x1440");
String downloadFilePath = "some file path";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilePath);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When I comment this line:

```
options.addArguments("headless").addArguments("window-size=2560x1440");
```

all is working fine and I download a couple of files, but Chrome doesn't work in headless mode.

When this line is not commented files don't download.

Can anybody tell my how I can download files using ChromeDriwer in headless mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the _headless_ and _headed_ executions working when the line is commented?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : out_path}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

download_path = './output/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", 
'/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 
'downloadPath': download_path}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```